# Having confusion in proof for finding the least value for the thickness of a simple graph.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, graph-theory

> Show that for any simple graph $G$with $n$ vertices and $e$
>   edges,thickness of $G$ $\ge$[$\frac{e}{3n-6}$].

Let $G$ be a simple graph with $n$ vertices and $e$ edges.By Euler's formula,we know that if $G$ is a planar graph then $e\le3n-6 $ i.e, we cannot have a simple planar graph with n vertices and more than $3n-6$ edges.**Hence,we require atleast [$\frac{e}{3n-6}$] planar subgraphs in order to draw all the edges of given graph.Hence thickness of $G$ $\ge$[$\frac{e}{3n-6}$]**

I'm not getting the highlighted part of the proof!

Comment: By thickness, do you mean girth?

Comment: @Justin:The thickness of a graph $G$ is defined as the minimum number of planar subgraphs  whose union is  $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bold statement is a bit vague, so let me make it more precise:

> Given a graph $G$ with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$ (where $|V|=n$ and $|E|=e$), suppose that $E = E_1 \cup E_2 \cup \dots \cup E_k$, where the subgraphs spanned by $E_1, E_2, \dots, E_k$ are planar. Then $k$ is at least $\left\lceil \frac{e}{3n-6}\right\rceil$.

To prove this: since the subgraph spanned by each $E_i$ is planar, we have $|E_i| \le 3n-6$ for each $i$. (This is the part where we use Euler's formula.) Therefore
$$e = |E| \le |E_1| + |E_2| + \dots + |E_k| \le (3n-6)k \implies k \ge \frac{e}{3n-6}$$ and since $k$ is an integer, we can turn that into $k \ge \left\lceil \frac{e}{3n-6}\right\rceil$.